# OK so I've located the "silent'" button

Tags: ringtones

Can't hear ringtones. Volume is up with buttons on left. Silent button shows red line. Does this mean it's on or off?

Thanks, padres

Comment: Try to flick it back and forth. What does the screen show?

Answer (score 1):

If your "Silent" button is showing the red line, your ringer is off. Flick it upwards (towards the screen) and your ringer should be on.